# Padding issue between columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i am having a small padding issue. removing the css makes no difference so I'm guessing I'm missing a row or similar. please see fiddle and image below:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/batman13/xBB5x/11533/

```
    <div class="row hidden-xs" style="height:100vh;">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:100%">
            <div class="col-sm-12 fill100 hidden-xs" style=
            "background-image:url('http://ajsroofingsolutions.com/images/branding.jpg');">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
               <h2>Jonny 5 Alive4 Big Screensssss</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="row hidden-xs" style="height:100vh;">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:100%">
                <div class="row" style="height:50%">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 fill50 hidden-xs" style=
                    "background-image:url('http://ajsroofingsolutions.com/images/branding.jpg');">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h2>Jonny 5 Alive Big Screen1sssss</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<div class="col-sm-6 fill50 hidden-xs" style=
                    "background-image:url('http://ajsroofingsolutions.com/images/branding.jpg');">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h2>Jonny 5 Alive2 Big Screensssss</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
 </div>


                <div class="row hidden-xs" style="height:50%">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 fill100" style=
                    "background-image:url('http://ajsroofingsolutions.com/images/branding.jpg');">
<div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h2>Jonny 5 Alive3 Big Screensssss</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

.fill100 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover; 
}


.fill50 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: What padding issue are you talking about? All I can see in the fiddle is a navbar and a bunch of images.

Comment: if your stretch the main window to make it bigger your see.

Comment: I've being doing some reading up and have better understanding of .row .container but am still struggling with my padding issue. Could someone be kind enough to put me out of my misery.

Comment: I'll try. Can you please provide more HTML as well as CSS and try replicating whatever you have so far in jsfiddle?

Comment: I've edited my original post and added additional html and css.

Comment: still no reply from my cry for help : (